# is ${x^{2/3}}$ the same as ${\sqrt[3]{(x^2)}}$ or ${(\sqrt[3]x)^2}$? domain?

Tags: roots, wolfram-alpha

is ${x^{2/3}}$ the same as ${\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ and ${(\sqrt[3]x)^2}$?
and what is domain of $x$?

Wolfram Alpha shows different results for [${x^{2/3}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%282%2F3%29) and [${\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%5E2%2C+3%29) representations.

Is domain dependant just on representation!?

Comment: Try some values!

Comment: As with all things, it depends on definitions. How do *you* define the three things? They all evaluate to the same thing on the non-negative reals, but then you have questions about definition on all the reals. You *can* define $x^{2/3}$ as being the same as the others on the reals, but some definition s do not.

Comment: Well, they *are* different. $x^{2/3}$ is `x^(2/3)` while $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ is `(x^2)^3`. Furthermore, exponentiation is not associative, so why would we expect the same result?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that Wolfram Alpha is secretly considering the functions in different contexts; for $x^{2/3}$ it is treating the $x$ as a complex variable, which can cause all kinds of shenanigans, whereas $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ has $x$ as a purely real variable, since there is no way that $x^2$ can be negative. Thus in the first case you must consider cube roots of $-1$, and in the second case you may always take the positive real root.

In short, the domain is NOT dependent on representation. Wolfram Alpha just likes to cut corners.

Comment: if i can represent the complex `x` in ${x^{2/3}}$ as a real `x` in ${\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$ than i can modify the context and the domain, just by another representation? And than the domain is dependent on representation? Or even after new representation, complex should be still complex and the domain will be still C?